# Google Maps with Geocode returning null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps to place markers from an array of zip codes but it only places about 10% of them. The rest return null results. I can't find the problem. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('pledge-map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });               
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var locations = <?php echo(json_encode($zips)); ?>        
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {                
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': locations[i]}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
          });
      }
    });     
  }
</script>
```

locations is an array of zip code:

```
locations =["20190","22192","20148","06078","95136","84120","53066","53404","48323","52404","72762","89701","39667","78073","78016","76013","15613","84010","77662","77407","30127","94566","14625","45629","27406","27289","02339","01864","39116","77079","10954","37683","72801","19341","14580","64133","29579","08527","32258","33433","60093","76691","78261","77095","19426","10469","92038","85208","67220","61031","85706","72223","21222","66224","34242","30224","56232","32746","08558","72712","14209","43015","52722","32779","33518","33578","60565","11239","17007","60623","77469","20165","20002","36116","20769","20815","34209","02301","60025","48158","38804","30736","01803","45040","48069","07463","53018","73008","80951","70785","72065","91510","91506","67209","22408","36849"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geocoder is subject to a quota and rate limits.  you are not checking for the error case (there is no code if the status returned is not OK).

Either:

1. look for the quota exceeded error code and handle it intelligently (add a delay and retry, only add the marker if it succeeds)
2. geocode the zipcodes offline and store the coordinates, use those to display your markers.

Comment: There is a "daily limit", but it is set up so you can geocode ~10 points (depending on server load) quickly.  The details aren't published (and may change).  The main goal as I see it being that nobody can abuse the service and everyone that is using it per the terms has a fair chance at it.